# How to get full length output from statevector draw

Tags: qiskit

```
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi 
circuit = QuantumCircuit(...)
state = qi.Statevector.from_instruction(circuit)
```

to get the state of my quantum circuit.

`state.draw(output='latex')` then gives a nice representation of my state.

This works pretty well. The only issue is that when the states get a bit long the output starts looking like this:

[image: Note how the dots in the middle indicates parts are missing]

Some parts of the state are missing, replaced by dots. How do I force qiskit to display the entire state? Is there some way of increasing the size of the output cell? I'm using a jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Statevector.draw`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.draw.html) method calls `state_drawer` function which in turn depends on `_state_to_latex_ket` function to generate the Latex representation.

`_state_to_latex_ket` function accepts `max_size` parameter to set the maximum number of non-zero terms in the expression which defaults to $12$.

As per documentation, if we set `max_size` to a large enough value when calling `Statevector.draw`, it should be passed to `_state_to_latex_ket` and the state shouldn't be truncated. However, it is not. It seems like a bug.

A workaround is to use `_state_to_latex_ket` directly as follows:

```
from IPython.display import Latex
from qiskit.visualization import state_visualization

prefix = "$$\\begin{align}"
suffix = "\\end{align}$$"
state_to_latex = state_visualization._state_to_latex_ket(state.data, max_size = 128)

Latex(prefix + state_to_latex + suffix)
```